# How to report performance of a Deep Learning Model (RMSE, R2) when lots of variation

Tags: neural-networks, descriptive-statistics, reporting, coefficient-of-variation

please bear with me because I'm a beginner. I have created an LSTM Model to solve a regression problem. The metrics that I am reporting are RMSE, MAE and R2. Unfortunately, my model might not be robust enough (also, not enough data), so everytime I run it after fine-tuning the hyperparameters, I get a different result. Sometimes the performance is good, sometimes it's really bad. My question is, how should I report this? Is it a good practice, to run it for example 10 times and report the average RMSE, MAE and R2? Thanks!

Comment: "Beginner" and "LSTM" do not really go together. There are infinite possibilities why this is happening and without going into many details we probably cannot answer this. If you do not know what you are doing then you are better off not doing it, you might just be modelling noise.

Comment: I'm not asking how to fix the model to make it more robust, I am asking how to report my results. It is a pretty straight forward question.